# How would you replace multiple characters in a string?

Tags: java, char

I want my program to replace every vowel in the inputted string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
         char vowel;
        vowel = 'a'+'e'+'i'+'o'+'u';

          Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
          System.out.print("Enter your name: ");
          String name = keyboard.nextLine();
          name = name.replace( vowel,'*');   
          System.out.print(name);
```

It just returns the string as normal but i want the vowels to be *'s.

Comment: Look at `String#replaceAll`. Note that it takes a *regular expression*.

Comment: You have declared the variable `vowel` as a character type and you are initializing it by `'a'+...+'u'` so it will simply sum up the ASCII codes of the vowel characters. That won't work here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
name = name.replace( vowel,'*');
```

To

```
name = name.replaceAll("[aeiouAEIOU]","*");
```

Answer (score 2):

When you do:

```
vowel = 'a'+'e'+'i'+'o'+'u';
```

You get a character equal to the values of those chars added up. Characters in java are stored as numbers. Instead, do String.replace on each vowel.

Replace:

```
name = name.replace( vowel,'*');
```

With:

```
name = name.replaceAll("[aeiou]",'*');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
name = name.replaceAll("(?i)[aeiou]", "*")
```

Comment: What's the reason for having (?i) ? in the expression. I know [aeiou] are the set of vowels OP is looking to replace

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, this:

```
char vowel;
vowel = 'a'+'e'+'i'+'o'+'u';
```

is not at all what you want. You're essentially performing regular addition here, treating chars as integers.

Now to get to your question: you can use `replaceAll` for this, but you also use a simple loop:

```
char[] rawName = keyboard.nextLine().toCharArray();

for (int i = 0; i < rawName.length; i++) {
    if ("aeiou".indexOf(rawName[i]) >= 0) {
        rawName[i] = '*';
    }
}

String name = String.valueOf(rawName);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name=name.replaceall("[aeiou]","*'s");
```